# How to extend the BndTool Repository with additional bundles?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-gemini

I try to add the gemini blueprint bundles to the [bndTool](http://njbartlett.name/bndtools.html) Repository. Unfortunately I could not find out how this works.
I have downloaded the [Gemini Blueprint](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/) bundles and have tried to add them as an additional repository (zipping the bundles). 
The "Osgi Bundle Repositories" dialog in eclipse seems the place to add additional repositories, but that did not work. It asks for an xml or zip archive, but I could not find out the format of the xml or the format of the zip archive. Zipping just all gemini bundles and adding the zip did not work. 
Does someone know how to add an additional repository or knows the featured way off adding 3rd party bundles to the bnd repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take the bundles, and drop them on your repository in the "Repositories" view to add them to Bndtools' basic repository.

If you want to refer to other repositories, you can use bnd's plugin mechanism to do this. In `cnf/build.bnd`, there is a line pointing to the plugins:

```
-plugin:        aQute.lib.deployer.FileRepo;location=${repo}
```

You can add multiple plugins, thus using more than one repository, by comma-separating them.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how to deal with other bundle sources, like the Spring Enterprise Repository?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the [OBR Bundle Repository](http://www.osgi.org/Repository/HomePage) of the OSGI alliance. The repository urls from that page can be added successfully to the "Osgi Bundle Repositories" dialog in eclipse (bnd-tools configuration).
 If one opens the url of an obr mentioned at the site above you can learn the xml format from it. 
 For today, bnd-tools rock!